# How to debug an ASPNET Core application in a subfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a ASPNET Core application that works fine on my machine with URL `https://localhost:5001/`, but not on the client's server, where the application's URL is `https://example.com/subfolder/`.

The problem seems to be an error in a redirect on one of the pages, where a user is sent to `/something` rather than `/subfolder/something`. I'm using relative URL's only. In the rest of the application, redirects work fine.

I was wondering if it is possible to debug the application in Visual Studio and have it run in a subfolder, preferably using Kestrel, but IIS Express might be an option too.

**Update after comments** While adding specifics about the problem, I found out that I was looking at it from the wrong angle. The actual problem seems to be that the application is started as `https://example.com/subfolder` (no trailing slash). Redirecting to `./something` (or just `something`) will result in `https://example.com/something`.

(My real question therefore would be: If `https://example.com/subfolder` is opened, how can I redirect to `https://example.com/subfolder/`? I'll first try to fix this myself, maybe it should be configured in the webserver. In the meantime, I'd still like to know if subfolders can be used in debugging)

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue is without seeing the actual error you're experiencing. It's likely a server configuration issue so there is nothing to debug, but that's just a guess

Comment: My assumption is that Apache/Nginx or whatever reverse proxy you are using is misconfigured. Basically, your reverse proxy should redirect the requests from the root "/" to something like this: "localhost:5001/subfolder/".

Comment: @Alexander Most redirects work fine, it's just this one that fails, so I don't think it's a server issue. Because I wanted to have a generic answer on how to debug an application in a subfolder, I left out the specifics, but maybe I should add them anyway. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 1):

In development, it seems you can't debug your program in subfolder.

I don't recommand you to spend a lot of time to serach how to do that, and I also suggest you use `IIS`. Because in `IIS`, it supports `Virtual Application`, and I think it is you want.

#### Steps:

1. create a main website, and create a virtual application.
2. choose the project folder as `Physical Path`, mainsite and virtualapplication.
3. open vs2019 as administrator, maybe you need open it twice,and one for main site and another for virtual application.
4. then you can [attach to a running process on your local machine.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019)
5. you can start your two webapp in one port, and you can debug them.